# PSU with dc stepdown buck

Tags: power-supply, led, current, dc-dc-converter, diy

I want to connect different LEDs that have these parameters (the LEDs I am using are just generic LEDs I got from ebay.):

Led 1: 6.4V - 7.2V  @ 0.7A

Led 2: 2.9V - 5.6V @ 1.9A

Led 3: 8V - 12V @ 3.4A

Led 4: 50V - 56V @ 2.8A

Recently I recovered a computer PSU that has an output of 12V, 16A.

Assume that the PSU is centrally located while each LED is in a different room (kind of a wheel).

If I connect the exit of the PSU with [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5-35V-3W-LED-Driver-700mA-PWM-dimming-DC-to-DC-buck-step-down-constant-current-/181433983936?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a3e4ee3c0) driver and for LED 1, [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/400362498785)  driver for LED 2, will it work? Or i am going to create a new smoke project?

Do the step down/step up converters be able to limit the current on the output or it will burn the LEDs?

Comment: Sorry, forgort to say that the drivers/buck converters are set in parallel, and that for LED 3 I would use this buck converter http://www.ebay.com/itm/301206315890 and for LED 4 this one: http://www.ebay.com/itm/gib-Boost-Converter-Step-up-Module-Power-Supply-600W-DC-DC-10V-60V-to-12V-80V-/191235833785?hash=item2c868b3fb9.

Comment: Actually the problem is that these are locally made while use a DC-DC,there are many problems,like Harmon incs,Some also have PWM implementation,Frequency Modulation, Hence the output is variable,hence there is a need to check them for these consistent harmonics,which I believe will be hard to find on ebay.

Comment: but if it is DC to DC, why the harmonics are an issue?

Comment: actually in PWM case they use duty cycle concept,but in frequency modulation they process depend on frequency where harmonics occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the driver states that it is constant current.  If they say that they are, and have an adjust (potentiometer) for current, it's likely that they are constant current.  With the links you provided, it looks as if 3 of them are constant current capable, while the remaining 1 isn't.

If you have doubts about if it is or isn't capable, you could also look at the datasheet for the regulator's controller chip.  In many instances of my purchases of these types of regulators off of ebay, I've noticed the designs are not far off of the reference designs in the datasheet.

An additional note is, you might want to run lower than the rated max current on your LEDs, until you know how much heat you'll be putting out with both the regulators and the LEDs.  That might help you iron out kinks and keep it from being a "smoke project".  You can always turn up the current later.